# getdir() for subfolder in root category

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0

i have this code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['featured_image']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['featured_image']['tmp_name']))) {
   try {
      $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('featured_image');
      $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
      $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

      // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file in a folder the magento way
      // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file directly in the $path folder
      $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

      $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;

      $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['featured_image']['name']);

      $data['featured_image'] = $_FILES['featured_image']['name'];
   }catch(Exception $e) {

   }
}

// handle delete image
else {
   if(isset($data['featured_image']['delete']) && $data['featured_image']['delete'] == 1)
      $data['image_main'] = '';
   else
      unset($data['featured_image']);
}
```

i want change this line

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;
```

and how can i change `media` directory to `media/blogpic`

i will thankful if you experts answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . "foobar";
```